# Broken live site after upgrade although upgrading locally and stage was no problem

Tags: 8, updating

I have just upgraded a site from Drupal 8.7 to 8.8, and I now have a broken site.

Pages on the site (mainly admin pages) are now giving the following error:

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "entity:path_alias" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager are: entity_revision, entity_revision:block, entity_revision:block_content, entity_revision:block_content:basic, entity_revision:block_content:paragraph_in_block_display, entity_revision:block_content_type ...

(I've truncated it because it goes on at some length about the entity types available)

Clearly something has gone wrong during the upgrade process. I've run all the module updates via composer, and database upgrades, and imported the config that was exported from a development instance of the site that has successfully been upgraded.

- `drush updb` tells me that all the database updates have been done.
- `drush cim` tells me that my config has been imported correctly.
- `drush en pathauto, path_alias` tells me that those modules are already installed.
- `drush cr` clears the cache, but does not resolve the issue.

I'm aware that the issue is due to the Pathauto / path_alias changes that occurred between D8.7 and D8.8, and I'm aware that I've probably missed a step during the upgrade process. That doesn't matter right now; what matters is how to fix it now that I'm in this situation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think your pathauto is not up to date, Install the latest version of pathauto and then do `drush updb`

Comment: Ideally you need to restore from backup and do the upgrade again, making sure to update the pathauto module first. The 8.8 upgrade notes specifically mention that if you don't do the pathauto upgrade first, you may lose data, so trying to backtrack from here without the help of a backup could be impossible

Comment: @NoSssweat - pathauto is up-to-date at v1.6

Comment: But did you update to pathauto 1.6 first, before you did the core 8.8 upgrade, or afterwards? It’s important to do it first

Comment: @Clive - yes, "restore and do again" is an option. In fact, I've just done exactly that on a staging site using a recent backup... I then ran the exact same upgrade process, and the issue didn't happen. So yes, that is an option, but I'd really like to fix it without restoring backup if possible.

Comment: @Clive - pathauto was at 1.6 prior to the upgrade.

Comment: The error strongly suggests that Drupal wasn't able to find the 1.6 version during your first upgrade attempt (maybe it was in the wrong folder, esoteric file system caching, something like that). No errors second time round would suggest it could find it second time around. As the core update was a destructive one, if Drupal couldn't act reliably against pathauto, you could have lost data. What (if any) data that would be is anyone's guess, so even if you managed to fix the service references that are causing the error you've listed, you may have an impossible data restoration task

Comment: That's why running again from a known good starting point is probably the best approach

Comment: To be clear, I ran this update locally and on the staging site successfully before attempting it on live. I had some issues locally but I resolved them and the staging upgrade went 100% smoothly. Staging very closely mirrors production. I've now also re-run it on stage, using last night's production backup, and still no problems, which is why I'm baffled why live went wrong. Additionally, the logging from the upgrade process on live shows the DB upgrades going through successfully, including the 8003 upgrade for path_alias entities.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that probably isn't anything to do with pathauto actually. Maybe you have some stale discovery cache entries that just aren't getting cleared. Try `drush eval "drupal_flush_all_caches();"`

Comment: Can you access the backend at least or login or nothing? What's you memory limit and PHP version on live? Do you manage your site with Composer, Git, both? Can you confirm the code really got updated on live?

Comment: Try to separate deployments for pathauto and D8.8: First update pathauto to v1.6, then in a second, separate deployment update to Drupal v8.8+. Don't push both updates in the same deployment to the live server.

Comment: Importing config sometimes doesn't install/update modules correctly. If you have SSH access to the live website just uninstall pathauto and re-install it (make sure you have a backup). If that's not an option, do as suggested by Hudri, deploy pathauto update first, do an updb and cr, after that deploy 8.8

Comment: Thanks for all the input everybody. Given the urgency and given the potential for corrupt data, we went with a full restore from backup. We will re-evaluate our position from here on how to get the upgrade done.